# Converting a string to an array with its letters

Tags: c#

Basically what I'm trying to do is take a string

```
string test = "hello";
```

and then turn it into an array as such:

```
string[] testing = { "h", "he", "hel", "hell", "hello" };
```

is this possible?

Comment: _"is this possible?"_ Yes, yes it is.

Comment: Yes but sounds like a homework question.

Comment: You just did. Pour yourself a beer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using *Linq*:

```
  string test = "hello";

  string[] testing = Enumerable
    .Range(1, test.Length)
    .Select(length => test.Substring(0, length))
    .ToArray();
```

Test:

```
  // h, he, hel, hell, hello
  Console.Write(string.Join(", ", testing));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this:

```
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            for(int i = 1; i <= hello.Length; i++) {
               list.Add(hello.Substring(0,i));
            }
             Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list.ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend Dmitry's LINQ version, but if you want a simple version that uses an array like your original question:

```
string input = "hello";
string[] output = new string[input.Length];
for( int i = 0; i < test.Length; ++i )
{
    output[i] = test.Substring( 0, i + 1 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string test = "hello";
    string[] arr = new string[] {test.Substring(0,1), test.Substring(0,2), test.Substring(0,3), test.Substring(0,4), test.Substring(0,5)};
```

Comment: Let the OP do that :P

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14084862)

Comment: @CDspace The code seems to produce the desired output.

Comment: It's giving the output as asked by the OP. And it's correct logically too. Why do you think its wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you use Linq.

```
    string test = "hello";      
    List<string> lst = new List<string>();

    int charCount = 1;

    while (charCount <= test.Length)
    {
        lst.Add(string.Join("", test.Take(charCount).ToArray()));           
        charCount++;
    }

    string[] testing = lst.ToArray();
```